# Number Theory: Determine $a$ and $b$ satisfying divisor relationships

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Determine integers $a$ and $b$ such as : $$a|b^2 \text{ and } b|a^2 \text{ and } (a+1) |(b^2+1)$$

I had tried to create a system , but I don't think that is the way to solve this problem

Thanks. :D

Comment: One trivial solution is $a=b^2$ :)

Comment: Another, quite simple one is $(a,b)=(k^2, k^3)$

Comment: There seems to only one more pattern $c^2(c^2-1),c(c^2-1)^2$

Answer (score 2):

**Case**: When $a$ and $b$ are perfect powers.

*Claim*: The values can be $a=k^{\alpha},b= k^{(3/2) \alpha}$

We use the fact that $a+1|a^{2m-1}+1$.

If we have $a=k^\alpha$, we need $k^\alpha+1|b^2+1 \text { which }\implies b^2=k^{(2m-1) \alpha}$

Notice that $b= k^{(2m-1/2) \alpha} \implies  2|\alpha$.

We check whether $a|b^2$ and $b|a^2$

Since $\alpha<(2m-1) \alpha$ , so we have $k^{\alpha}|k^{(2m-1) \alpha} \implies a|b^2$ .

We need $2 \alpha >\dfrac{(2m-1)}{2} \alpha \implies 5>2m \implies m=1,2$

Therefore, we have $b=k^{\frac{3}{2} \alpha}$, when $a$ is a perfect power.